# Updating a collection view when new collection is fetched

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have a collection instance and then a collection view instance on page load that populates from the server a region and wineries from that region.

This is being called on my home page in a jQuery ready function...

```
var regionWineriesList = new RegionWineriesList();
var regionWineriesListView = new RegionWineriesListView({collection: regionWineriesList, map: Map.map});
regionWineriesList.fetch({
    success: function(response) {
        $('.wineries-scroll').prepend(regionWineriesListView.render().el);
    }
});
```

This is working great.

I also have an autocomplete view that when clicked, does a fetch for a new set of data. It is in the findWineries() function.

```
var RegionsView = Backbone.View.extend({

el: 'body',

initialize: function(options) {
    this.region_input = $('input#RegionLocation');
    this.winery_input = $('input#WinerySearchHome');
},

events: {
    'click input#RegionLocation': 'autoCompleteSetup',
    'click .pulldown-arrow': 'autoCompleteSetup'
},

autoCompleteSetup: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.options = {minLength: 0, source: this.collection.toJSON()};
    this.region_input.autocomplete(self.options);
    this.region_input.autocomplete('search', '');
    this.region_input.autocomplete({
        select: function(event, ui) {
            self.winery_input.val('Search By Winery Name');
            self.findWineries(ui.item.label);   
        } 
    });
},

findWineries: function(label) {
    var newRegionWineriesList = new RegionWineriesList();
    newRegionWineriesList.fetch({
        data: {region: label}, 
        reset: true
    });
}

});
```

This is also working in that it fetches the new data from the server.

I can't seem to figure out how to update the view once the new data is retrieved.  I tried to bind the collection view to the collection but nothing is happening.

Here's the model, collection and collection view. I am leaving out the model view. Please advise if I need that and I will edit.

```
var RegionWinery = Backbone.Model.extend();

var RegionWineriesList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: RegionWinery,
    url: '/regions/regions_wineries.json',
    parse: function(response){
        return response.wineries;
    }

});

var RegionWineriesListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    className: 'wineries',

    initialize: function(options) {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
        this.map = options.map;
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        this.collection.each(function(winery) {
            var marker_view = new MapMarkerView({model: winery, map: this.map });
            var regionWineriesView = new RegionWineriesView({model: winery, marker_view: marker_view});
            this.$el.append(regionWineriesView.render().el);
        }, this);

        return this;
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am already calling fetch in the second block from an autocomplete. That is working correctly. The response is coming back from the server. I was under the impression that when a collection or model changes, the view is updated automatically so I was trying to bind the collection view to the collection.

Comment: So the only collection that it recognizes is the regionWineriesList instance and when I create the new newRegionWineriesList instance it doesn't know about that?

Comment: Again, thanks for your explanations. So in code block 2, where I fetch new data, how do I update the collection. Am I able to do this without creating a new instance.  I wasn't able to access the `regionWineriesList` in my function. It said it was undefined.

Comment: That would be great. I am posting some more code above so you can see what I have. I may be approaching this all wrong. New to backbone so I am still trying to grasp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the view would look more like this:

```
var RegionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //...
    findWineries: function(label) {
        this.collection.fetch({
            data: {region: label}, 
            reset: true
        });
    }
});
```

then whatever creates that would create the regional list and whatever else cared would listen to the same collection:

```
var newRegionWineriesList = new RegionWineriesList();
var v = new RegionsView({ collection: newRegionWineriesList });
someOtherView.listenTo(newRegionWineriesList, 'reset', something_that_handles_the_reset);
```

A better way would be to set up a global event bus:

```
window.yourApp = window.yourApp || { };

yourApp.events = _({}).extend(Backbone.Events);
```

Then whatever it is that wants to know about a region change could listen to the global event bus:

```
this.listenTo(yourApp.events, 'new-region', function(region) {
    // deal with the new region, this would usually be a method
});
```

and your `RegionsView` could broadcast the new region with a `trigger` call:

```
this.region_input.autocomplete({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        self.winery_input.val('Search By Winery Name');
        yourApp.events.trigger('new-region', ui.item.label);
    } 
});
```

One nice advantage of this approach is that it is easy to have several things listening for the region change without having to tightly couple everything.

Comment: Thank you so much for this excellent explanation. I am going to refactor the code and let you know what I come up with. Again, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, there was half a meter snow on the weekend that needed my attention :)

Comment: No need to apologize. You have really given me a lot to think about and build off of. I spend at least a month+ in Vail every year teaching skiing. When the snow calls...